Extracting raster values based on the unit length of polygon
I aim to extract the average values of a land coverage raster based on each unit length of polygon.
For example, as shown by the picture below, the gray area over the map is polygon, the south to north direction is the length of polygon (length=600km). How do I extract the average values of land coverage data on the first 1km, the second 1km, the third 1km and so on until all the average land coverage on 600km length is collected.(which indicates it will result in 600 average land coverage values being extracted from south to north direction)

I know it can be used the zonal statistics plugin on QGIS to extract the mean by polygon. However, I find this function can only extract one value based on a whole polygon, rather than based on the unit length of a polygon. How can I do this?

Create a grid of 600 squares of unit length size and polygon extend and run raster analysis for this grid.

Are all your polygons north-south oriented rectangles?

@Bera, the direction of the polygons is oriented toward its' length, so it could be shifted to any direction since it is determined by the direction of the length of the polygon. In this case, it is a north-south oriented rectangles. But I
